# Connecting the same GUI to two or more python files

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

i am building a small project which involves 4 python files which have their separate functionalities. There is however, a `main.py` file which uses all the others by importing them.

Now, i have to build a GUI for this project, which i am building within the `main.py` file. My problem is that some of the other files have functions which `print` on the console, when the whole project is run, i want those functions to `print` on the GUI instead. So, how do i print the text from the other file in a `Text` field created in the main file.

**main.py**

```
import second as s
from tkinter import *

def a():
    field.insert(END, "Hello this is main!")

root = Tk()
field = Text(root, width=70, height=5, bd=5, relief=FLAT)
button1 = Button(root, width=20, text='Button-1', command=a)
button2 = Button(root, width=20, text='Button-2', command=s.go)
root.mainloop()
```

**second.py**

```
def go():
    print("I want this to be printed on the GUI!")
#... and a bunch of other functions...
```

I just want that when user presses the button-2, then the function `go()` prints the text on the `field`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consider it the best way to try add `field` as an argument of function `go`.

Here is my code:

**main.py**

```
import second as s
from tkinter import *

def a(field):
    field.insert(END, "Hello this is main!\n")

root = Tk()

field = Text(root, width=70, height=5, bd=5, relief=FLAT)
button1 = Button(root, width=20, text='Button-1', command=lambda : a(field))
button2 = Button(root, width=20, text='Button-2', command=lambda : s.go(field))

#to display widgets with pack
field.pack()
button1.pack()
button2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**second.py**

```
from tkinter import *


def go(field):
    field.insert(END, "I want this to be printed on the GUI!\n")
    print("I want this to be printed on the GUI!")
    #something you want
```

The screenshot of effect of running:)

[image]

Comment: Whoah! It was just this? Thanks a lot!